# How to use greater_equal predicate with includes() algorithm?

Tags: c++, predicate, std

I was trying to use `greater_equal predicate` with `includes() algorithm`. I wrote the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9, 10};
    int b[] = {4, 3, 5, 1, 2, 6, 8, 9, 7, 10, 11};
    unsigned int alen = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int), blen = sizeof(b) / sizeof(int);
    std::sort(a, a + alen);
    std::sort(b, b + blen);

    if(std::includes(a, a + alen, b, b + blen, std::greater_equal<int>()))
        std::cout << "a contains b" << std::endl;
}
```

I was expecting that this would output `a contains b` since the predicate `greater_equal predicate` should be satisfied all elements in `b` that are in `a`, but it doesn't. I am a little confused about its usage. Please help.

Comment: ["The second version expects them to be sorted with the given comparison function `comp`."](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/includes) The arrays are not sorted (with respect to your comparator).

Answer (score 4):

Like all the algorithms on sorted sequences, this requires the comparator to be the same as the one used to sort the sequence; and `greater_equal` is not valid for that since it doesn't give a strict ordering.

`includes` doesn't check whether the comparator is true for each pair of inputs; it checks whether the two values are equivalent according to the ordering defined by the comparator. That is, it checks that `!comp(a,b) && !comp(b,a)`. That will never be true for a non-strict comparator like `greater_equal`.

Comment: Should this output `a contains b` if I use `less predicate` since the arrays would be sorted in this order?

Comment: @mozart: No, because `a` doesn't contain `b`. (Although, since `b` isn't sorted, it could do anything).

Comment: Then what is the use of predicates in this? Can you provide any link for more information? I have sorted `b` also. Haven't I?

Comment: @mozart: The comparator defines an ordering, specifying how the sequence was sorted. It must be a *strict weak ordering* returning `true` if the first argument comes strictly before the second, and `false` if it comes after or is equivalent to it. `greater` and `less` are fine; `greater_equal` is not since it returns `true` for equivalent values - it is not *strict*. The set operations (including `includes`) require both sequences to be sorted according to that comparator.

Comment: @mozart: `b` is not sorted: the first elements are `4,3,5`.

Comment: But I have sorted them using algorithm sort(), they would be sorted in ascending order. Won't they?

Comment: @mozart: Sorry, I didn't notice the sorting. In that case, using `less` as the comparator (or calling the overload that doesn't take a comparator and defaults to `less`) is well defined. It returns `false` since `a` doesn't include `b`: there's no `11` in `a`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40319/discussion-between-mozart-and-mike-seymour)